# send SCPI command through python socket module

Tags: python, sockets

I am using python's socket module to send a simple SCPI command to my Keysight device, but I get a blank response. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my simple script.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
print("connecting")
s.connect(("192.168.25.7",5024))
print("sending")
s.settimeout(10)
s.send("*IDN?\n")
print(s.recv(2048))
```

I expect this script to return

```
➜  ~ python hack_na.py
connecting
sending
Agilent Technologies,E5063A,MY54100104,A.03.00
➜  ~
```

But if I run the script, I get this output instead.

```
➜  ~ python hack_na.py
connecting
sending

➜  ~
```

I can confirm that I get the desigred output with telnet.

```
➜  ~ telnet 192.168.25.7 5024
Trying 192.168.25.7...
Connected to 192.168.25.7.
Escape character is '^]'.

SCPI> *IDN?
Agilent Technologies,E5063A,MY54100104,A.03.00
SCPI>
telnet> Connection closed.
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two versions are not the same.

You're not seeing any output in the first case because you're not actually sending a complete message from the socket to the server. The `telnet` protocol [uses `\r\n` to end lines](https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/31.htm), not just `\n`. So you'd need to do `s.send("*IDN?\r\n")`.

But really, you should use a better tool for the job. Python's `socket` module is  just direct bindings to the BSD socket interface, usually used for building low-level networking applications. As such, you'll need to worry about annoying details like the line-endings yourself. A better alternative is to use a higher-level library, more tailored for your purpose. [`telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html?highlight=telnet#module-telnetlib) is a builtin module for operating as a telnet client, or you could use a [third-party library](https://pypi.org/project/easy-scpi/) explicitly for SCPI.

Comment: telnetlib — Telnet client

Source code: Lib/telnetlib.py

Deprecated since version 3.11, will be removed in version 3.13: The telnetlib module is deprecated (see PEP 594 for details and alternatives).